# how to handle redirect in laravel when using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

im using ajax in laravel

im using a custome request
and a custom middleware for authentication

as u know my authentication middleware will redirect a user if user not loged In

but when im using ajax i dont know how to handle this situation
i wrote this jquery function which is work correctly

```js
function addBasket(url) {
    var formData = {
        product_id: $("#addbasket").attr('value')
    }
    $.ajax({
        data: formData,
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            data.forEach(el => {
                $("#count").text(el.count)

            })
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('fail')
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
}
```

the above code will send request if user loged in
but sometimes when user is not loged In obviously it will get error for log which i dont know how i can catch it and handle it

any help will b appreciate

Comment: what the error you're getting? probably you are using the auth middleware on your route

Comment: yes i use my own auth middleware , and correctly works when user is not loged in ,i will error but not in json way , like normall redirect error

Comment: do you want to redirect the page if ajax throw an error?

Comment: yes, when user is not loged in i want to redirect

Comment: you can check `error response status_code` if it returns an `401` status then you can redirect the user to the login page @Abbas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can redirect if ajax throw any error :

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
   window.location = '/login';
}
```

You can specified the error code :

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
   if (xhr.status == 401) {
       window.location = '/login';
   } elseif (xhr.status == 419) {
       window.location = '/';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your js code in blade file
redirect to your specific route

```
...

error: function (error) {
    location.replace("{{ route('your_route_name') }}")
}
```